# No connection to client network via OpenVPN site-to-site connection

Tags: networking, openvpn, ping, synology-diskstation, asuswrt-merlin

I am trying to connect two of my homes (and maybe more than that later) via an OpenVPN site-to-site connection. My goal is so that all clients on all sites are able to talk to eachother.

But for some reason I cannot manage to get a connection from Site A to the clients in Site B. Vice versa it works perfectly fine.

Do I have an error in my OpenVPN config?
Did I forgot to push any routes?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

### The situation

Here is how the setup looks like:

[image: Network Map]

#### Site A

- ISP Modem/Router

  - OpenVPN port `1194` is forwarded to Unifi USG
- Unifi USG as Router / DHCP

  - Network: `192.168.200.1/24`
  - connected via WAN port to ISP Modem/Router
  - OpenVPN port `1194` is forwarded to Synology NAS
  - Static route `192.168.100.1/24` to Synology NAS
- Synology NAS with fixed IP `192.168.200.200`

  - OpenVPN server using the Synology VPN Server Package
  - OpenVPN server network: `10.0.10.0/24`

#### Site B

- ISP Modem/Router
- ASUS RT-AC68U router with merlin firmware

  - Network: `192.168.100.1/24`
  - connected via WAN port to ISP Modem/Router
- OpenVPN client connects to Site A/OpenVPN server

  - Client IP `10.0.10.6` in this example. I tried fixed cleint IPs as well, but that did not change the outcome

#### Additional devices

- more clients can connect via OpenVPN and will be assigned IPs in the range of `10.0.10.x`

### Problem

- ✅ OpenVPN connection is established successfully
- ✅ Site B Router (`192.168.100.1`) can ping Site A OpenVPN server (`192.168.200.200`)
- ✅ Site B Router (`192.168.100.1`) can ping Site A router (`192.168.200.1`)
- ✅ Site B Router (`192.168.100.1`) can ping Site A clients (eg `192.168.200.6`)
- ✅ Site B Client (eg `192.168.100.129`) can ping Site A OpenVPN server (`192.168.200.200`)
- ✅ Site B Client (eg `192.168.100.129`) can ping Site A router (`192.168.200.1`)
- ✅ Site B Client (eg `192.168.100.129`) can ping Site A clients (eg `192.168.200.6`)
- ✅ Site A Router (`192.168.200.1`) can ping Site B router (`192.168.100.1`)
- ❌ Site A Router (`192.168.200.1`) **cannnot** ping Site B clients (eg `192.168.100.10`)
- ✅ Site A Client (eg `192.168.200.6`) can ping Site B router (`192.168.100.1`)
- ❌ Site A Client (eg `192.168.200.6`) **cannnot** ping Site B clients (eg `192.168.100.129`)

---

I already tried to run `tcpdump -eni any icmp` on site B router.

When I ping site B router (`192.168.100.1`) from site A client (`192.168.200.6`), it works:

```
21:33:04.416012  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.200.6 > 192.168.100.1: ICMP echo request, id 1038, seq 1, length 64
21:33:04.416165 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.100.1 > 192.168.200.6: ICMP echo reply, id 1038, seq 1, length 64
21:33:05.418067  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.200.6 > 192.168.100.1: ICMP echo request, id 1038, seq 2, length 64
21:33:05.418147 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.100.1 > 192.168.200.6: ICMP echo reply, id 1038, seq 2, length 64
21:33:06.419075  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.200.6 > 192.168.100.1: ICMP echo request, id 1038, seq 3, length 64
21:33:06.419153 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.100.1 > 192.168.200.6: ICMP echo reply, id 1038, seq 3, length 64
```

However when I ping **site B client** (`192.168.100.129`) **from site A client** (`192.168.200.6`), **it fails**:

```
21:37:08.038559  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.200.6 > 192.168.100.129: ICMP echo request, id 1039, seq 1, length 64
21:37:09.070567  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.200.6 > 192.168.100.129: ICMP echo request, id 1039, seq 2, length 64
21:37:10.110696  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.200.6 > 192.168.100.129: ICMP echo request, id 1039, seq 3, length 64
21:37:11.150865  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 192.168.200.6 > 192.168.100.129: ICMP echo request, id 1039, seq 4, length 64
```

Vice versa, when I ping **site A client** (`192.168.200.6`) **from site B client** (`192.168.100.129`), **it works**:

```
21:39:11.565543  In bc:5f:f4:63:a9:46 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 192.168.100.129 > 192.168.200.6: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 230, length 40
21:39:11.565543  In bc:5f:f4:63:a9:46 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 192.168.100.129 > 192.168.200.6: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 230, length 40
21:39:11.565665 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 10.0.10.6 > 192.168.200.6: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 230, length 40
21:39:11.573657  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 192.168.200.6 > 10.0.10.6: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 230, length 40
21:39:11.573715 Out 60:45:cb:59:fd:d0 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 192.168.200.6 > 192.168.100.129: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 230, length 40
21:39:11.573736 Out 60:45:cb:59:fd:d0 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 192.168.200.6 > 192.168.100.129: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 230, length 40
21:39:12.584996  In bc:5f:f4:63:a9:46 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 192.168.100.129 > 192.168.200.6: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 231, length 40
21:39:12.584996  In bc:5f:f4:63:a9:46 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 192.168.100.129 > 192.168.200.6: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 231, length 40
21:39:12.585099 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 10.0.10.6 > 192.168.200.6: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 231, length 40
21:39:12.592692  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 192.168.200.6 > 10.0.10.6: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 231, length 40
21:39:12.592751 Out 60:45:cb:59:fd:d0 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 192.168.200.6 > 192.168.100.129: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 231, length 40
21:39:12.592777 Out 60:45:cb:59:fd:d0 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 76: 192.168.200.6 > 192.168.100.129: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 231, length 40
```

---

#### OpenVPN Server Config

(Synology NAS `/usr/syno/etc/packages/VPNCenter/openvpn/openvpn.conf`)

```
dev tun

# make all clients aware of local site
push "route 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.0.10.0 255.255.255.0"

# forward routes to other sites
route 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0"

management /var/run/openvpn.sock unix

server 10.0.10.0 255.255.255.0

client-config-dir /usr/syno/etc/packages/VPNCenter/userIPs/
client-to-client

dh /var/packages/VPNCenter/target/etc/openvpn/keys/dh3072.pem
ca /var/packages/VPNCenter/target/etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /var/packages/VPNCenter/target/etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /var/packages/VPNCenter/target/etc/openvpn/keys/server.key

max-clients 5

comp-lzo

persist-tun
persist-key

verb 3

#log-append /var/log/openvpn.log

keepalive 10 60
reneg-sec 0

plugin /var/packages/VPNCenter/target/lib/radiusplugin.so /var/packages/VPNCenter/target/etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.cnf
verify-client-cert none
username-as-common-name
duplicate-cn

status /tmp/ovpn_status_2_result 30
status-version 2
proto udp6
mssfix 1450
port 1194
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
```

I have a client config dir with a file for my vpn user:

(Synology NAS `/usr/syno/etc/packages/VPNCenter/userIPs/<vpn user name for site b>`)

```
# set static ip address for this client
#ifconfig-push 10.0.10.100 255.255.255.0

# make server aware that the 192.168.100.0/24 address range is handled by this client
iroute 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0
```

#### OpenVPN Client File

```
dev tun
tls-client

remote <site A dynamic host name> 1194

float

#redirect-gateway def1

dhcp-option DNS 192.168.200.1

pull

proto udp

script-security 2


comp-lzo

reneg-sec 0

cipher AES-256-CBC

auth SHA512

auth-user-pass

setenv CLIENT_CERT 0

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
```

---

Update: This is how the USG (Router on Site A) is configured to route traffic to the Synology

[image: Static Routes on the USG (Site A)]

Update: Routing Table on the Synology. I did not add any routes here, They were automatically added by the OpenVPN server.

[image: Routes on the Synology (Site A)]

Comment: You might want to add your routing tables.   I've not gone through this in any depth, but I wonder how the synology is seeing the local devices through the USG.   I suspect the problem is here - ie if the USG is acting like a switch between the devices and synology the devices won't know to route VPN traffic to it, and if the SG is routing their is likely a hairpin nat issue lurking there.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I updated my post

Comment: If there was an award for "Best question asked by a new user", I'd give it to you.

Comment: hey @mtak. nice to hear that :-). I tried my best to give you as much information as possible. Still, any help is appreciated. Maybe I am reading the `tcpdump` results wrong. Can somebody explain me what they can read from the data I posted?